# Make the form size bigger

Tags: form, list-form

is it possible to make the form screen bigger which goes onto a new tab and just fills the whole screen instead of the form just taking a bit of my screen on the right , im using the newest sharepoint powerapps version

Comment: Which version of SharePoint are you asking about?  I *think* you are asking about SharePoint Online and PowerApps forms…. But that’s an assumption.